# Using REST API with jQuery Easyautocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, rest, easyautocomplete

I'm having trouble getting the [easyautocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-remote) plugin to connect to my data source and pull the title of each object within the JSON. A sample of the JSON looks like this:

```
data: [{
       id: "1",
       title: "bob",
       permalink: "/user/folder/bob",
       type: "user"
}]
```

I'm making the call to my REST API and trying to get the `title` value, which I'll also need to get the `type` of each object as well.

```
var q = $("#global-search").val();
var options = {
    url: "https://search.domain-name.com?q=" + q,

    getValue: "title",

    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};

$("#global-search").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

The only error I'm getting is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`.

The url structure for the search requires that it be the base url `http://search.domain-name.com` with a query parameter of `?q=` for the search term.

how can I fix this so that my request is actually sent and receives a response as well as searches by the type and title of in each object of the data array returned?

This is my current fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xb45t46q/)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you,
1. I will Check the url to know is that working properly. 
=> Using Chrome Debuging tool and see network i/o will be helpful.
=> write console.log to find the problem.

2. the code looks okay but when I checked the jsfiddle. The "input id="provider-remote" "  and your jquery id were different, you may check it.
3. Sometime, jsfiddle does not support external url through https => http might be helpful for debuging.

Good Luck

Comment: The div name was an oversight, thanks. I've checked the console and not getting anything else logged. I've replaced the url with a test url from jsonplaceholder and its working. How can I append the value from the textbox as a query parameter to the url so that it follows my original requirements. I've updated the fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/xb45t46q/1/) to show it working with the json placeholder api, but need to be able to append they query parameter.